# how integrate a scroll-down effect with velocity.js in a react application without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, velocity.js

I'm trying to create a scroll-down effect in a single-react-app. I'm using velocity.js, but I don't know how could I integrate this library in my component without jquery. Does someone have an idea to solve it?

my code HTML for an arrow-icon looks like this:

```
<div className="row">
  <NavLink to="#" className="icon down" id="go-down">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowCircleDown} className="scroll"/> 
  </NavLink>
</div>
```

I found this code in jQuery, but I have to use vanilla javascript:

```
var $icon = $(".ion");
var $down = $("#go-down");
var $up = $("#go-up");

$icon.velocity({
  translateY: "10px"
}, {
  loop: true
}).velocity("reverse");

$down.on("click", function() {
  $up.velocity("scroll", {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeInBack"
  });
});

$up.on("click", function() {
  $("body").velocity("scroll", {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeInBack"
  });
});
```

It could be super nice if someone can help me with this. Thank you a lot!

Comment: This could be useful https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/